# Python variables in Apache Airflow not holding data

Tags: python, variables, airflow

The code below works fine when I run it in the Terminal:

```py
data = []

def _step_one():
    for i in range(10):
        data.append(i)

def _step_two():
    print(f'data: {data}')

_step_one()
_step_two()
```

It prints `data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

But when I run the same on Apache Airflow `data` is empty `[]` as first initialized

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import timedelta

data = []

def _step_one():
    for i in range(10):
        data.append(i)

def _step_two():
    print(f'data: {data}')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Test DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=3)
)

step_one = PythonOperator(
    task_id='step_one',
    python_callable=_step_one,
    dag=dag
)

step_two = PythonOperator(
    task_id='step_two',
    python_callable=_step_two,
    dag=dag
)

final_step = BashOperator(
    task_id='notify',
    bash_command='echo "Operation Completed!"',
    dag=dag
)

step_one >> step_two >> final_step
```

I'm new to Python so I may be committing a newbie mistake, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass data between tasks in that way.

As your tasks can run on a different machine they do not shares the variables. If you want to pass data between tasks, you should use XCom:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/concepts.html#xcoms

Comment: That explains it, I'll read the article and report back later